# Eclipse ide needed to be integratewd with MISRA rules

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, misra

How can I integrate [misra](/questions/tagged/misra) rules with [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse)

Comment: I hate the MISRA Rules. Or better i hate some of the Rules and my MISRA Rule checker which sometimes doesn't unterstand the Rules...

Comment: Are you using a rule checker? You can tell eclipse to run it from the command line when you build or save.

Answer (score 1):

[QaC++](http://www.programmingresearch.com/qacpp_main.html) is a rule checker commercial tool from PRQA with a eclipse integration plugin.
It's not free, but it is the best checker I've seen with a **very high check coverage**.

Answer (score 0):

[PC Lint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62946/misra-standard-for-embedded-software) is generally considered the most pragmatically useful of the reasonably-priced tools with Misra checking capability.

It is pretty straightforward to semi-integrate any command-line checking tool into Eclipse, either as an 'External Tool' or (usually better) calling it from your project makefile under a [dedicated target](http://www.bezem.de/2009/08/using-pc-lint-in-eclipse-no-plug-ins-required/).